# Getting the name of the connected printer to print the POS receipt in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, printing, pos

I know there is a way to get all available printers in C# using `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters`. But how to get the name of the printer which is attached to say, a USB port? Do we need to hard code the name of the printer? Because, if so, we'll have to change the printer name in the code if the application is run on a different system, which might use a different printer.

How do real POS systems do this? How could I generalize the printing functionality of the application? I am using the library ESC-POS-USB-.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The API will be for standard Windows desktop printers.
The main function is graphic printing on cut sheet paper.

Most receipt printers for thermal roll paper used in POS are connected to a serial port or a network and print using the ESC POS command mainly for characters.

There are many ways to use it to send commands directly from the serial port.
However, there is also a way to use a standardized API that abstracts the functions of the POS printer.

The name of the specification is called UnifiedPOS.
The actual mechanism is OPOS, POS for.NET, JavaPOS, Windows.Devices.PointOfService, etc.

Please search based on those keywords.